# How to caputure box bounded images in YOLO v3 output display video

Tags: image, capture, yolo

How can I store box bounded images from result of YOLO v3 code??

I trained some images and weights were set.
then I input videos and detected object that I'd trained

I want capture the video when object is detected with box bounded

Answer (score 0):

You could just record the whole time you are capturing. I'm not sure if you just want the frame for a recognized object.

In your code, there must be something for a result so it knows to draw the bounding boxes. I'd use something like the following so you only get images with good scores:

```
if result and confidence > 0.95:
        cv2.imwrite(f'./images/{image_name}')
```